# What are the buildings in this photo of Atlanta?

Tags: identify-this, architecture, atlanta

I can identify some of the buildings, but there are a few I'm not sure about.

[image]
<sup>*My identifications, plus the 11 I'm not sure of*</sup>

[image]
[image]
<sup>*I increased the lighting but had to crop out part of the building on the far right*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Daylight photo of Atlanta from roughly the same vantage point*</sup>

3D Google Maps view from approximately the same spot the daylight photo was taken:  [Link](https://www.google.com/maps/@33.7216946,-84.3817683,33a,20y,350.26h,83.39t/data=!3m1!1e3!5m1!1e4)

Imgur album of photos, some of which have a few of the buildings illuminated by fireballs: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GirX.jpg)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_buildings_in_Atlanta

Comment: I have to wonder why are you trying to identify the buildings on a night photo?  And from several miles away?  Would it not be simpler to go into Atlanta and identify the buildings one by one?

Comment: @Karlson - 1. I had a more comprehensive list than wiki, and labeled the ones I recognized, but I'm not sure about the ones I didn't label.  2.  The night shots are from a TV show.  3.  I didn't take any of the photos, and I live in NJ, so going to Atlanta would be expensive and far more complicated than asking here.

Comment: @Karlson  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IATZKJ2zLAU

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia's [List of tallest buildings in Atlanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_buildings_in_Atlanta) article lists all of the downtown buildings by name and has a nice overlay map of the exact area you took a photograph of:

[image: atlanta skyline]

Comment: I'm clicking on some of the buildings Wad has numbered bit I'm guessing they aren't in the list?